# Using String Envelope on Ksaop Android

Tags: android, soap, envelope

I want to know how can i use a String envelope in my Soap call method. Here is my envelope :

```
String soapEnvelope = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org\">\n"
      + "<soap:Header/>\n"
      + "<soap:Body>\n"
       + "<tem:GetItems>\n"
        + "<tem:catId>"+categoryId+"</tem:catId>\n"
        + "</tem:GetItems>\n"
     + "</soap:Body>\n"
  + "</soap:Envelope>\n";
```

I normally use

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME_MAINCATEGORIES);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransportSe = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
httpTransportSe.debug = true;
SoapObject response = null;

try{
  httpTransportSe.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
  response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
  SoapObject main = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(1);
  SoapObject list = (SoapObject)main.getProperty(0);

  //String a = Integer.toString(list.getPropertyCount());
  //Log.i("property count", a);

  for(int i = 0; i<list.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    Categories c = new Categories();
    SoapObject nsoap = (SoapObject)list.getProperty(i);

    if(nsoap != null){
      c.setId(nsoap.getProperty("Id").toString());
      c.setMainId(nsoap.getProperty("MainID").toString());
      c.setName(nsoap.getProperty("Name").toString());
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return categories;
```

kind of approach. But i need to add a parameter to this call, which is an integer value. I tried to add

```
request.addParameter("myValue", myValue);
```

where myValue is a parameter required to call this function. Here is portion of code:

```
public ArrayList<Item> getItems(int myValue){
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME_ITEMS);
  request.addProperty("myValue", myValue);
  Log.i("catId", String.valueOf(myValue));
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
  HttpTransportSE httpTransportSe = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  httpTransportSe.debug = true;
  SoapObject response = null;
```

I tried both String and `int myValue params`, request always returns as "myValue" 0 (it returns items for 0 even if you enter 1,2,3,4 etc.). I made a research and learned that I need to create an envelope and give my parameter there. Now i created a String envelope that I gave above, how will i integrate it to my call ? Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

try adding parameters are follows

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME_ITEMS);
PropertyInfo paraId = new PropertyInfo();
paraId.setName("YOUR PARAMETER NAME");
paraId.setValue("YOUR PARAMETER VALUE");
paraId.namespace=NAMESPACE;
paraId.setType(String.class); // or INTEGER whatever your type is...
request.addProperty(wallpaperCatId);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i also tried that one before, result is still same, returning like my parameter is 0 on every parameter.

Comment: are you using KSOAP2 library ?

Comment: Yes, "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar".

Comment: try using this "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" as i have also faced some problems  on 3.1.1 version.

Comment: I was able to make it work with request.addProperty by fixing my Namespace, it was "http://tempuri.org", while it had to be "http://tempuri.org/". A singe "/" was causing trouble. Thanks for help !